# data isn't reflected on the app from database when I enter new data and return to this page

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

The data from mysql server isn't automatically reflected in my app when I fill a form to enter the data from my app and comeback to the page... But if I login again or do a hot reload the data is reflected and I'm not sure where to add a setState({}) and what to write inside of it so please tell me how to update my list automatically.........

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:finance_returns/Screens/Admin/AdminLogin.dart';
import 'package:finance_returns/Screens/Admin/CreateUser.dart';
import 'package:finance_returns/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AdminDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminDashboardState createState() => _AdminDashboardState();
}

class _AdminDashboardState extends State<AdminDashboard> {
  Future getData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('http://$ip/EmployeesDB/admin/read.php');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dashboard'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AdminLogin(),
                    ),
                  );
                })
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push( context, MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => Register()), ).then((list) => setState);
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                ),
                label: Text("User"))),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      List list = snapshot.data;
                      return ListTile(
                        //leading: GestureDetector(
                          //child: Icon(Icons.mode_edit_outline),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Register(
                                  list: list,
                                  index: index,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                            debugPrint('Edit Clicked');
                          },
                        //),
                        title: Text(list[index]['username']),
                        subtitle: Text(list[index]['level']),
                        trailing: GestureDetector(
                          child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              var url =
                                  Uri.parse('http://$ip/EmployeesDB/admin/delete.php');
                              http.post(url, body: {
                                'id': list[index]['id'],
                              });
                            });
                            debugPrint('delete Clicked');
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    })
                : CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        )
      );
  }
}
```

This is the registration page:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:finance_returns/Screens/Admin/AdminDashboard.dart';
import 'package:finance_returns/components/text_field_container.dart';
import 'package:finance_returns/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  final List list;
  final int index;
  Register({this.list, this.index});
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController user = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pass = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController level = TextEditingController();
  bool editMode = false;
  Future addUpdateData() async {
    if (editMode) {
      var url = Uri.parse("http://$ip/EmployeesDB/admin/edit.php");
      http.post(url, body: {
        'id': widget.list[widget.index]['id'],
        "name": name.text,
        "username": user.text,
        "password": pass.text,
        "level": level.text,
      });
    } else {
      var url = Uri.parse("http://$ip/EmployeesDB/admin/user_register.php");
      var response = await http.post(url, body: {
        "name": name.text,
        "username": user.text,
        "password": pass.text,
        "level": level.text,
      });
      var data = json.decode(response.body);
      if (data == "Error") {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "This user already exists!",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0);
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Successfully registered",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 16.0);
        // Navigator.pop(
        //   context,
        //   MaterialPageRoute(
        //     builder: (context) => AdminDashboard(),
        //   ),
        // );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.index != null) {
      editMode = true;
      name.text = widget.list[widget.index]['name'];
      user.text = widget.list[widget.index]['username'];
      pass.text = widget.list[widget.index]['password'];
      level.text = widget.list[widget.index]['level'];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Create/Update Users',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFieldContainer(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Name',
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  controller: name,
                ),
              ),
              TextFieldContainer(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Email id',
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  controller: user,
                ),
              ),
              TextFieldContainer(
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.lock,
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  controller: pass,
                ),
              ),
              TextFieldContainer(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'level (eg:member,admin,HR)',
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  controller: level,
                ),
              ),
              MaterialButton(
                color: kPrimaryColor,
                child: Text(editMode ? 'Update' : 'Create',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white)),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    addUpdateData();
                  });
                  Navigator.pop(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AdminDashboard(),
                    ),
                  );

                  debugPrint('Clicked Button Button');
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing the navigation before getting data and that setState is updating the state of the current page, not the previous one. Try this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  await addUpdateData();
}
```

and in the first page:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => Register(
      list: list,
      index: index,
    ),
  ),
).then((_) => setState(() {});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Comment: Thanks man your solution worked and the new created user can be seen but there's another issue but on my dashboard page I'm displaying the user' level like HR,admin,etc inside of subtitle but if I edit that through the app it isn't being reflected on the dashboard page

Comment: yes the it is because if I create new data it is being reflected however if I edit some user data it gets updated in the database but not on the screen